# JAVA: How to calculate sum of user-inputted numbers in a loop (numbers are stored in same variable)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sum, addition

This code is part of a receipt-program. I looped it so that users can input item prices (20 item maximum). I need to print the sum of all item-prices. Note that all item-prices are stored into the same double variable `newItemPrice`. Is this even possible? If not, please give me an idea on another way to do this.

```
while(x < 20){//maximum of 20 items

    x++;//item # (x was decalred as an integer of 1)

    System.out.println("\nEnter new item's price");
    Scanner newItemPriceSC = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double newItemPrice = newItemPriceSC.nextDouble();//scans next double (new item's price)

    System.out.println("ITEM # " + x + "\t" + "$" + newItemPrice);//item prices
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("type \"no more!\" if there are no more items\ntype any other word to continue");
    Scanner continueEnd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answ = continueEnd.nextLine();       

    if(!(answ.equals("no more!"))){
        continue;
    }


    if(answ.equals("no more!")){
        break;//ends loop
    }

    break;//ends loop (first break; was for a loop inside of this loop)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new variable before your while starts:

```
double total = 0;
```

Then add one line of a code in your cycle:

```
Scanner newItemPriceSC = new Scanner(System.in);//your code
Double newItemPrice = newItemPriceSC.nextDouble();//your code
total +=newItemPrice; //this is the new line
```

When the cycle will be ended, the "total" variable will contain the sum of all the prices entered.

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck on that problem for over an hour. But, if you don't mind, tell me how your solution works. What's the significance of declaring "total" outside of the loop?

Comment: @ben1123 You declare this variable outside of the loop and it equals 0 at that point. Then the loop starts. You are getting your next Double (four example, 5). Then this next number is being added to the variable total. Then loop goes for its next cycle, but your total variable is already equal 5 but not zero. You are getting another double (for example, 12), you add it to the total so the total now equals 17 (5 + 12). And so on, until your loop stops. The expression "total +=newItemPrice;" means total = total + newItemPrice.

Comment: If you declared the total variable in the loop, it would have been recreated and initialized with 0 on every iteration of the loop. Which means you wouldn't have any information remaining from previous iteration, that's why you declare this variable outside of the loop.

Comment: that's exactly what was happening before. The variable kept resetting to zero every other time. It makes a lot of sense now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use newItemPrice to accumulate all the prices by just incrementing it with the currently scanned price.

```
Double newItemPrice += newItemPriceSC.nextDouble();
```

However, then you lose the ability to print out the price in the next line.

You'll need to introduce a temporary variable with the results of newItemPriceSC.nextDouble() so you can print it out. If you lose the requirement of printing out the item price, then you don't need the temporary value.